# How to write a regular expression for a range from -50.0 to 0.0? Both inclusive

Tags: regex, math, numbers

I have tried 0.0 to 50.0.

```
^(?:50(?:\.0)?|[0-4]?[0-9](?:\.[0-9])?|0?\.[1-9])$
```

Don't know how to include only negatives and a zero.

Comment: Why don't you use parseFloat and check whether it is in the range?

Comment: Because i have to use it in a json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although there are much better ways to do so, this is my solution, checked with [regex101](http://regex101.com):

`^(?:\-50(?:\.0)?|\-[1-4][0-9](?:[\.][\d]{1})?|\-[0-9](?:[\.][\d]{1})?|0(?:\.0)?)$`

Comment: Works. If you would like to explain me(even superficially) how you did it, it would be great. thanks anyway.

Comment: Sure! Although regex101 explains it better then me, we divided our matching to 4 cases: 50 (with or without decimal point and zero), -49 to -10 (w/ or w/o zero again), -9 to -0 (can be altered, w/ or w/o zero) and zero (same deal again), limited to only one digit after the period, anything else you would like me to explain? :)

Comment: It works on the Regex site, but when i put it in my project in a json file, -25.5 or any decimal like -xx.x or -x.x does not work but -x works. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: What programming language or regex engine are you using?

Comment: I'm using it in Mbcui json and then it's going to Pal actions and Javascript. it's weird that only -xx.x is not working. rest all is fine.

Comment: I can't find anything that goes by that name…

Comment: ok, do you think this should work in all json that are used it javascript?

Comment: It should work on js as with regex101, it has nothing to do with JSON, it's purely regex.

Comment: You can try fiddling around with it in regex101.

Comment: i'm trying from half an hour but the expression you gave is perfectly right. And the other cases are working so. is there any way i can show you screenshots?